# Possible to “Attach” images to multiple posts without uploading twice from Add media Section?

Tags: attachments

How can I attach images to a post which have already been attached to other posts without having to upload them twice?

I don't want to insert the images into the post, I simply want to attach the same set of images to multiple posts.

Comment: See [Codex how to insert image in posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages). Is this what you're searching for? Asking because you tagged the question with [tag:plugins].

Comment: by mistake it is taged to plugin, i m looking for adding images to post once uploaded, rather upload again and again

Comment: Then see the link in my comment above. Also please read into the [help/on-topic] "On Topic" page to see what is on topic. Questions about wordpress.com hosted blogs are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

From selecting the 'Add Media' button you can select 'Media Library'. Do this instead of the 'Upload Files' option. This way you can reuse a already uploaded image.

Is this the answer you were searching for?

Comment: in this image is inserted, but when i click on "Uploaded to this post" drop down it is not showing that inserted image,it only shows uploaded images which is proper attached with post.?

Comment: this is not , what i want, i want how can i also insert image from add media gallery as we upload new in add media to the related post, that is inserted in posts table as attachment with the mime type.